# How to add elements to np.array with several conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, list-comprehension

I need help to solve the following problem:

First create an empty array `f` with the same shape (i.e. 2x3x5) as `d` using `np.empty`.
Populate the values in `f`. For each value in `d` :

- if it's larger than `d_min` but smaller than `d_mean`, assign **25** to the corresponding value in `f`.
- if a value in `d` is larger than `d_mean` but smaller than `d_max`, assign **75** to the corresponding value in `f`.
- if a value equals to `d_mean`, assign **50** to the corresponding value in `f`.
- assign **0** to the corresponding value(s) in `f` for `d_min` in `d`.
- assign **100** to the corresponding value(s) in `f` for `d_max` in `d`.

I am trying to use list comprehensions to do this, instead of for loops.

This is what I did:

```py
import numpy as np
f = np.empty([2,3,5])
f1 = [25 if d_min<item<d_mean else 75 if d_mean<item< d_max else 0 if item == d_min else 100 for out_list in d for in_list in out_list for item in in_list]
print(f1)
```

This is what I get:

```py
[75, 75, 25, 25, 25, 25, 75, 75, 75, 25, 25, 100, 25, 25, 25, 75, 75, 75, 25, 75, 75, 75, 75, 25, 0, 25, 75, 75, 25, 75]
```

The final result should be something like this:

```py
array([[[ 75.,  75.,  75.,  25.,  75.],
        [ 75.,  75.,  25.,  25.,  25.],
        [ 75.,  25.,  75.,  75.,  75.]],

       [[ 25.,  25.,  25.,  25., 100.],
        [ 75.,  75.,  75.,  75.,  75.],
        [ 25.,  75.,   0.,  75.,  75.]]])
```

Can you help me find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending all the computed values to the same list. In this particular case, you should instead do:

```
f1 = [[[25 if d_min<item<d_mean else 75 if d_mean<item< d_max else 0 if item == d_min else 100 for item in in_list] for in_list in out_list] for out_list in d]
```

You can also do the same computation by using numpy comparison and addition:

```
f1 = 25 * (d > d_min) * (d < d_mean) + 75 * (d < d_max) * (d > d_mean) + 0 * (d == d_min) + 100 * (d == d_max)
```